# Htacces entering loop after moving error documents

Tags: .htaccess, loops

Site enters an endless loop when i try to move error pages in subfolder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([-\w.]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 
DirectoryIndex home.php
ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
ErrorDocument 502 /502.php
ErrorDocument 504 /504.php
```

and after i move my pages

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([-\w.]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 
DirectoryIndex home.php
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php
ErrorDocument 502 /errors/502.php
ErrorDocument 504 /errors/504.php
```

(also tried with out the slash befor error)

otherwise works perfect . Can the problem be that i'm running on localhost(xampp) or the virtual host?

Comment: you could also always check your apache logs to see what the actual error it's proving.

Comment: What URL causes looping error?